# Unable toboot with Nvidia GTX 750 ti, even with latest beta drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

Yesterday I got a Nvidia GTX 750ti for my htpc (ubuntu headless 12.04) but the computer wont boot with it installed. 
I've tried booting with ***nomodeset*** parameter and installing the latest beta driver from nvidia but I get black screen on boot. The machine does not seem to boot as I cannot ssh into it or invoke ctrl-alt-f*

Comment: What driver are you using? `nvidia-current`

Comment: Any reason not to mark [Leonardo's answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425140/unable-toboot-with-nvidia-gtx-750-ti-even-with-latest-beta-drivers#answer-432940) as the accepted one? It worked for me, and it seems that for others too.

Answer (score 10):

I have ubuntu 13.04 64 bit and same problem: Nvidia GTX 750ti and no boot.
I solve by following these steps:

1. go on [nvidea driver download](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) I have get NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-334.21.run
2. put it in a folder you remember (your home) and make it executable (`chmod u+x ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-334.21.run`)
3. `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`
4. `sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`
5. `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` or `sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
6. add at the end this lines

> blacklist vga16fb
>   blacklist nouveau
>   blacklist rivafb
>   blacklist nvidiafb
>   blacklist rivatv

and save

`sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` or better if you like vim: `sudo vim /etc/default/grub`

find

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
>
> and change it to
>
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"

`sudo update-grub`

now you have to go text-only:

> use CTRL+ALT+F1 to go on text-only
>   to come back on graphic mode use CTRL+ALT+F7
>
> 1. `sudo gdm service stop` or `sudo service lightdm stop`
> 2. `sudo sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-334.21.run`
> 3. it give you some warning on pre build script I have continued
> 4. it ask you to accept some condition, you give all yes
> 5. let it change xorg.profile for you
> 6. `sudo reboot`

if you have trouble at reboot you can do a new reboot and start in recovery mode:

1. Advanced options
2. recovery mode

after this if you continue by the normal boot you can login in graphical mode but after you are logged in you have to repeat step 7,8,9

at next login you can boot on graphical mode.

this procedure has worked for me I hope work for you too.

regards

Comment: +1 I had no graphics card in my system (using integrated graphics), then I installed an NVidia GTX 750 ti and Ubuntu would not go past grub. My Windows was still functioning fine so I knew it had to be the graphics card. This solution fixed everything for me, thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working now! I followed this steps but using a newer driver version "NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.58.run" and  it worked right after rebooting. 2 things to share: `1`. after excecuting `CTRL+ALT+F1`, I could only see a black screen, so I had to shh from another machine to continue with the steps. `2`. My problem was slightly different from the one described on this thread. I could use Ubuntu but at a very low res, and couldn't use any of the graphic card power.

Comment: work for me ! Thx

Comment: there is not 9th step here?

Comment: I have correct the list numbers

Answer (score 2):

After booting with nomodeset and installing ubuntu then **only follow step 7 & 8 from Leonardo Saracini**

then add following ppa;

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa

sudo apt-get update & upgrade

sudo apt-get install nvidia-337 ( dont install that before command above)
```

restart and voila ;) (by the way I'm using 14.04)

Answer (score 1):

I too have had some issues with the new Nvidia cards. Here's more commands that helped me.

boot in recovery mode with networking on.

navigate to your home directory.

`cd /home`

download Nvidia 750ti drivers... If you've got a different card, like a 760ti or 780ti check Nvidia's website when you go to download the driver, the 'Agree and Download" button is the link I used for the wget command below. If the drivers are different, (I don't think they are) this may solve some issues for others as well.

```
sudo wget http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/334.21/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-334.21.run
```

Then continue were Leonardo left off above. Thanks man, I'd +1 if I could.

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by going:

1. into recovery mode
2. enable networking [on],
3. go to root shell, type `cd /home`
4. then `sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 nvidia-settings`
5. then `sudo reboot` and you are done.