# New Nvidia Graphics card drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

Hi I am writing this as I have an issue with my Nvidia drivers. I have a Nvidia 750Ti running on a Xubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I have had problems with my nvidia drivers before and solved them using this answer: [Unable toboot with Nvidia GTX 750 ti, even with latest beta drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425140/unable-toboot-with-nvidia-gtx-750-ti-even-with-latest-beta-drivers)

After installing the drivers the graphics card have been working perfectly, until the kernel upgraded. After that I would again have driver problems and then would install the newest drivers again.

So here are my questions:

1. Do I have to install the drivers from the Nvidia website manually every time there is a kernel upgrade?
2. I saw that there are experimental drivers for the new graphics cards: https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa. I have heard that they experimental and could potentially damage your system, but they do have the newest Nvidia 337.25 drivers. Are these safe to use and do they update automatically (sudo apt-get upgrade or GUI method)?

Which of the two options would be better?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to your question:

1. Yes, you do have to re-install nvidia driver every time kernel upgrades.
2. Experimental drivers is why they call **experimental** they can work flawlessly and they can go off anytime, use it at your own risk.

And for the last I recommend to use `Proprietary` driver from Ubuntu repos or the `closed driver` from Nvidia official source, which is considered to be the best solution for your video card, it includes all the latest features and support as it's being developed by your graphic card native vendor.

In addition read this [manual](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66328/how-do-i-install-the-latest-nvidia-drivers-from-the-run-file/423619#423619) written by me.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately proprietary drivers are not available to me, so I guess I will continue manually installing the newest drivers from nvidia.

Comment: I'm glad to help you, don't forget to accept the answer if you're satisfied with it or provide your solution. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm with Ubuntu 14.04 and a GeForce 750 ti, too. I had to go through the same procedure to actually get my machine to boot. Now, originally I just downloaded the driver and installed it manually. At first it seemed to have worked, but I later ran into problems. I guess they were cause by me, making some mistakes at some point in the manual process, but at any rate, I could not solve them and had to re-install Ubuntu.

The second time I went with adding the edger's PPA and installed the driver from there. It worked like a charm, since all necessary changes were applied for me (blacklisting nouveau, for example).

The stability of the driver can be questioned - I have a lot of weird flickering (mostly in the browser; not at all in games) and some other mysterious issues, but none of them are show stoppers.

Regarding whether or not you automatically receive updates: good questions, I'd love to know the answers to these myself. What I do know is that once you've added the edger's PPA, you can simply select from all available drivers within the software center. See Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpjps.jpg

About the kernel/upgrade, I have no idea. And that said, sorry for the incomplete answer - I wanted to write a comment, but my reputation didn't allow it. I still wanted to share the little info I had. Hope this helped and I'm not breaking any rules.

Comment: The problem is that I have to reinstall drivers twice since I got my new graphics card two weeks back. It is very stable, but having a package source from nvidia would make it much easier for me. Do the edgers's PPA drivers update automatically at every kernel upgrade?