# How to install Nvidia proprietary drivers?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I get pretty poor performance with Nouveau, so I want to install the proprietary drivers. However, I've had to reinstall Ubuntu TWICE. I tried the "173" driver, black screen. "nvidia-current", black screen. I have no "Additional Drivers", so I don’t know what is going on. I have a GeForce GTX 750 Ti.

Comment: read this article https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia you can also take a look at my other workaround if you're interested [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66328/how-do-i-install-the-latest-nvidia-drivers-from-the-run-file/423619#423619)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/425140/unable-toboot-with-nvidia-gtx-750-ti-even-with-latest-beta-drivers

Comment: It looks like you need at least version 334, which isn't even available in vivid.  Who knows why the nvidia driver is so outdated

Answer (score 1):

Search additional drivers in the unity search box, click to open it. You can enable the proprietary driver there.