# Ubuntu stopped working after update

Tags: drivers, nvidia, login-screen, display-resolution

After the actualization of yesterday (3/16/2016) my graphical interface shows malfunctioning (I have a nvidia gtx 750 ti and the login screen has a resolution of 640x480). But what is worse is that although I try to enter my session with the correct password, the screen turns black and it take me back to the login screen.

I do not know if the las actualization has done something to the nvidia drivers since I had to install them because ubuntu did not recognize my graphic card natively.

I followed [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425140/unable-toboot-with-nvidia-gtx-750-ti-even-with-latest-beta-drivers) to install the nvidia drivers.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I have already fixed it, I had just to reinstall drivers again. 
Sorry for bothering.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use this driver http://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/84721/en-us?

I've red that with your card, it works fine. Nvidia cards have oft problems.

You can try another display manager (`sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm` [install gdm /lightdm if you have only one]).

If you don't need all the card's capabilities you can also try the nvidia glx package after a purge of installed drivers.